# Input and output stream

Tags: c++, iostream

Is it safe to open an input stream to a file, while an output stream to the same file is open (but not writing to it)
(Single threaded)

Comment: why would you have an output stream to a file open if you're not writing to it?

Comment: I have a class that writes to a log file and I want to keep the stream open so I can write to the log file any time. I also want to open an input stream every once in a while to check the size of the log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially, it depends on the system.  The system may not allow it.  Other than that, as soon as you have a stream open for writing, and more than one stream open on the same file (regardless of direction), you have to worry about buffering.  In your case, if you do a flush before opening the stream for reading, and do not write while you're reading, it should be OK.  If you're trying to write, and read the last thing you wrote, it is more difficult, because there is nothing which you can do to resynchronize a read buffer with the file.  And if you're trying to write through two different streams, it's even more problematic.  (Although if the writes should always be appended at the end, and you can arrange when you flush, opening the files with `std::ios_base::app` should do the trick.  But that won't help reading.)

Answer (score 3):

It's probably 'unsafe' in the same way that riding a bike without a helmet is unsafe. Things can go wrong a lot more easily, but if you are smart and careful about it, it shouldn't matter. However, there isn't really a need to do this, you could simply close the output stream when you want to read in and then reopen it once you are done reading.